# Laravel InertiaJS website too slow with SSR (Server Side Rendering)

Tags: node.js, laravel, seo, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I have a website built on Laravel and using Inertia with Vuejs as a frontend, with SSR (Server Side Rendering) website is too slow in the production server, it takes more than a minute to load the page and eats a lot of RAM and CPU as well when I turn off the SSR (Server Side Rendering) then website runs very fast and consuming fewer system resources.

Is there any way to optimize the performance as SSR (Server Side Rendering) is needed for SEO purposes?

I have checked the logs in server and didn't find any issue, everything went normal except performance

Comment: When activate SSR it takes more time than SPA. I think the problem it self from the SSR. If you are looking for SEO purpose you can use livewire + alpinejs. Inertia is good for web app which does not need SEO.

If you are in high traffic and use SSR, it would cost lots server resources